# Как правильно сделать сборку на Docker уже готового Django проекта со стандартной базой Sqlite?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, docker, docker-compose

Создал небольшой сервер на django и встроенном sqlite. Уже битый день пытаюсь "завернуть" его в docker. В Dockerfile я указал только папку с сервером. Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ADD requirements.txt /cars/
WORKDIR /cars/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Requirements.txt:

```
Django>=2.0,<3.0
djangorestframework
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: spartakode/sqlite3:latest
    volumes:
      - .db/database.db:/db/db.db
  cars:
    build: cars/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/cars
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Однако в папку db я ничего не добавлял. Я понимаю что туда надо что-то добавить, но не понимаю что именно т.к db.slite3 находится в папке cars. Если брать отдельно мой джанго проект, то все работает. Миграции и тд. сделаны. При переносе папки с проектом и запуском python manage.py runserver все работает безотказно. Структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске docker-compose up выдает следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросы:1)Что нужно сделать в моем случае чтобы Django проект заработал со стандартной базой данных(Sqlite) на Docker?
2)Как правильно собрать на Docker готовый Django проект? Может можно как-то по другому?

Comment: а зачем вам отдельный контейнер для sqlite, это же не слиен-серверная бд, ваш db контейнер не будет принимать запросы от основного приложения, а просто запускаться и ничего не делать + у вас скорее всего опечатка в пути .db/database.db

Comment: То есть можно удалить db из docker-compose.yml и саму папку db? Я пытался сделать как здесь https://hub.docker.com/r/spartakode/sqlite3/

Comment: да, т.к. она все равно подключается через `- .:/cars` в `cars` контейнере

Comment: да и вообще, я не совсем понимаю, зачем тут нужны контейнеры, если вы не добавляете код при билде, а подключаете его как volume, да это удобно для дебага, но получается что вы создаете "изолированный" контейнер, к котором нужно просто запустить процесс python и все, а учитывая что вы работаете на Windows, то это дополнительная виртуалка, получается вы просто запускаете процесс вместо хост машины, в контейнере, который находится в виртуалке, не сильно ли накладно?

Comment: Странно, мне пришлось удалить еще и volumes:
      - .:/cars иначе выдавало ошибку. Однако теперь все заработало. Походу я плохо понимаю его функцию.